# BsonValue and custom classes in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to use `$push` in an update query in mongodb, with the c# driver.

The `Update.Push(...)` method requires a string name (that's fine), and a BsonValue to be 'pushed'.  This is where I run into problems. I'm trying to push a non simple type to the field's array.

For example:  `{ $push : { "arrayfield" : { "a" : 7, "b" : 12 } } }`

This works fine in the Mongo console, but I can't figure out how to make my object into a BsonValue.  I've tried `BsonValue.Create(myObjectInstance)` but that gives me an error saying the .NET type cannot be mapped to a BsonValue.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know two approaches:

1. `Update.PushWrapped<MyObject>("arrayfield", myObjectInstance);` //c# driver >= 1.0
2. Or convert your class to `BsonValue` yourself via `ToBsonDocument()` extension method.

   `Update.Push("arrayfield", myObjectInstance.ToBsonDocument());`

Comment: I ended up using .ToBsonDocument(), but the .PushWrapped is something I was completely unaware of, thanks for that!