# Adding a New Subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to add a subdocument to a list in an existing document. The documents look like this:

```
public class EtaMembershipDocument : DocumentBase
{
    public List<EtaAssociationDocument> EtaAssociatonDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to how to add a new `EtaAssociationDocument` to the list using C# and MongoDB. This is my latest attempt:

```
var collection = this.DataStore.GetCollection<EtaMembershipDocument>(EtaMembershipsCollectionName);

Update.AddToSet("EtaAssociationDocuments", BsonValue.Create(etaAssociationDocument));
```

On that last line, I get this error:

> .NET type EtaAssociationDocument cannot be mapped to a BsonValue.

The problem is that I don't even know if this is how I'm supposed to add a subdocument in the first place. If my approach is correct, what can I do to resolve the error? If my approach is incorrect, how should I be doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BsonValue and custom classes in MongoDB C# Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732663/bsonvalue-and-custom-classes-in-mongodb-c-sharp-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a duplicate, but since the original question is quite old, its answer is kind of outdated. You no longer have to meddle with manual conversion to `BsonDocument`. Instead, you can use the strongly-typed helpers, which is quite helpful for refactoring:

```
collection.Update(
    Query<EtaMembershipDocument>.EQ(p => p.Id, someId),
    Update<EtaMembershipDocument>.AddToSet
        (p => p.EtaAssociatonDocuments, documentToAdd));
```

Unlike `PushWrapped` and `ToBsonDocument`, this will ensure that the set you are referring to implements `IEnumerable<T>` and that `documentToAdd` is of the same type as the type parameter `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. That duplicate answer is over two years old now, so your answer is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if you happen to know of an elegant way to do this type of thing for *updating* a subdocument, that question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21287485/279516.

Comment: Well, the currently only answer to that question is from Robert Stam, he wrote the C# driver and works for MongoDB, so I think that's an authoritative answer :)